# Close FTP connection with ncftpput command line

Tags: ssh, backup, bash, ftp

I have a bash script to make backup from server to FTP. The backup does in a few minutes, but the FTP connection is still active for 20 hours.

How can i close it?

The important line is:

```
CMD="ncftpput -R -v -u "user" -p "password" -P 21 remotehost.com /localdir"
```

So, i have read in documentation that i can close connection with "close" command, but, how can i put it to close after the backup it's done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look to -X (if you transfer only one file) or -T options.